# Prevent babel from hyphenating words shorter than five letters

Tags: babel, hyphenation

Is there a way to prevent babel from hyphenating words shorter than five letters? While still allowing the parts on either side of the hyphen to be a minimum of two letters?

Comment: This is done at the engine level and only `luatex` provides such a feature, with `\hyphenationmin=4` (it’s language dependent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Javier commented, with luatex you can set

```
\hyphenationmin=4
```

for classic TeX there is no specifc parameter but in practice there will not be so many 4 letter strings that hyphenate in the middle, and even fewer if you restrict to valid words, and you can simply list them in `\hyphenation`

```
\lefthyphenmin=2
\righthyphenmin=2

\showhyphens{
atic orla insane manly
}

\hyphenation{atic orla}

\showhyphens{
atic orla insane manly
}

\bye
```

logs

```
[]  \tenrm at-ic or-la in-sane man-ly
```

then

```
[]  \tenrm atic orla in-sane man-ly
```

showing hyphenation suppressed for (just) the four letter words.

```
\lefthyphenmin=2
\righthyphenmin=2

\showhyphens{
atic orla insane manly
}

\hyphenation{atic orla}

\showhyphens{
atic orla insane manly
}

\bye
```